# Ubuntu 16.04 - Python 3.5 - VirtualEnv - unable to create venv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I've been having issues with virtualenv. Installed but error-

```
The 'virtualenv==15.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Installed version 15.0.1 but I dont think the installation went right. The error now is-

```
bash: /usr/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
```

And it is correct as there is no directory named "virtualenv" at the specified location.

In my attempt to resolve this, I have removed python 2.7 just to rule out any conflicts.
Also - I do see a directory named "virtualenv_15.0.1+ds-3ubuntu1_all.deb" at /var/cache/apt/archives. Could this be causing the issue? What do I do?

Comment: Not finding the `virtualenv` in the `bin` directory definitely means that the installation was not successful. Try install `virtualenv` as a python package with `pip` as the [docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) suggest

Comment: I see what you're saying dstrants.  Let me also inform yout hat being a noob I happen to have installed/uninstalled the virtualenv a buch of time using bith sudo apt-get and pip/pip3. I suspect multiple installations and uninstallations could be causing this issue. What do I do?

Comment: Don't worry, we've all been there. first of all I suggest you run `which virtualenv` on your terminal to find out if there is a virtualenv installation.

Comment: I ran it and it said: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
Which is great.
But now when I try - "virtualenv venv" it creates a folder named "venv" but terminal says
"OSError: Command /home/snake/venv/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1"

Comment: Did you install python3? Try running `python3 --version` to check it out

Comment: Yes .. I have Python 3.5.2